# How to match two lists of strings with regex in Python

Tags: python, regex, string, list

I have two lists of strings in Python. One of them is a list of desired strings, the other is a larger list of different strings. For example:

```
desired = ["cat52", "dog64"]
buf = ["horse101", "elephant5", "dog64", "mouse90", "cat52"]
```

I need a True/False for whether the second list contains all the strings in the first list. So far I did this with:

```
if all(element in buf for element in desired)
```

However, now I need the list of desired strings to have some regex properties. For example:

```
desired = ["cat52", "dog[0-9]+"]
```

I've looked into the `re` and `regex` python libraries but I can't figure out a statement that gives me what I want. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/regex

Comment: @VishalSingh thanks, I have looked into this module but I couldn't find any documentation on how it handles lists. Do you know if it can handle a list for matching/searching?

Comment: It looks to me you want to test the string match, not the regex. Am I right?

Comment: @tshiono sorry if I wasn't clear, I want the statement to return true if `buf` contains all the strings in `desired`. So in the above example it would return true, as `buf` has "cat52" and "dog64", and they match the desired list `desired = ["cat52", "dog[0-9]+"]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to test whether `any` of the strings in `buf` match each regex in `desired`, and then return `True` if `all` of them do:

```py
import re

buf = ["horse101", "elephant5", "dog64", "mouse90", "cat52"]
desired = ["cat52", "dog[0-9]+"]

print(all(any(re.match(d + '$', b) for b in buf) for d in desired))
```

Output:

```
True
```

Note that we add `$` to the regex so that (for example) `dog[0-9]+` will not match `dog4a` (adding `^` to the beginning is not necessary as [`re.match`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html?highlight=re%20compile#re.match) anchors matches to the start of the string).